# PCF Kafka with Kerberos authentication - Running Locally but Failing in PCF

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kerberos, cloud-foundry

I am facing issue when Connecting to Kafka through SpringBoot using Kerberos Authentication. I am using the custom Kafka connection manager with following details -

```
          bootstrap-servers-sasl: node1:9094, node2:9094, node3:9094
          protocol: SASL_SSL
          mechanism: GSSAPI
          kerberos:
            service:
              name: kfkusr
          jaas: 
            config: "com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required useKeyTab=true storeKey=true keyTab=\"#keytab-name#\" principal=\"abc/node2@domain.NET\";"
```

where `#keytab-name#` will be replaced at runtime with following values as -

My Local PC - `C:/Users/MyPC/AppData/Local/Temp/abc.node2_d2254866264751402128.keytab`

PCF - `/home/vcap/tmp/abc.node2_d2215947326380395062.keytab`

Locally the application is running fine and messages are going to Kafka. But when running on PCF fails with following exception -

```
2019-08-09T14:40:46.481-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] WARN [9f-3868cbe47d81] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient o.a.k.c.NetworkClient.processDisconnection(NetworkClient.java:585) - ||||||||||||||Connection to node -1 terminated during authentication. This may indicate that authentication failed due to invalid credentials.
...
...
Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms
...
...
Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='<my payload>' to topic <test_topic> :: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
```

**UPDATE 1 -**

After adding the krb5.conf file and it has default realm

```
[libdefaults]
  default_realm = mydomain.NET
```

the authentication error disappeared but still have following error

```
Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms
```

Once Debug enabled for `org.apache.kafka: DEBUG` is showing new error as -

```
2019-08-14T09:49:51.947-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] DEBUG [d3-5b28248c661c] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient o.a.k.c.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:907) - ||||||||||||||Initialize connection to node node1:9094 (id: -1 rack: null) for sending metadata request
2019-08-14T09:49:51.947-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] DEBUG [d3-5b28248c661c] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient o.a.k.c.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:762) - ||||||||||||||Initiating connection to node node1:9094 (id: -1 rack: null)
2019-08-14T09:49:51.948-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] DEBUG [d3-5b28248c661c] o.a.k.c.s.a.SaslClientAuthenticator o.a.k.c.s.a.SaslClientAuthenticator.setSaslState(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:209) - ||||||||||||||Set SASL client state to SEND_HANDSHAKE_REQUEST
2019-08-14T09:49:51.948-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] DEBUG [d3-5b28248c661c] o.a.k.c.s.a.SaslClientAuthenticator o.a.k.c.s.a.SaslClientAuthenticator$1.run(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:134) - ||||||||||||||Creating SaslClient: client=abc/node1@domain.net;service=kfkusr;serviceHostname=node1;mechs=[GSSAPI]
2019-08-14T09:49:51.949-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] INFO [d3-5b28248c661c] o.a.k.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder o.a.k.c.n.SaslChannelBuilder.buildChannel(SaslChannelBuilder.java:119) - ||||||||||||||Failed to create channel due to : org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to configure SaslClientAuthenticator at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.configure(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:125) at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.buildChannel(SaslChannelBuilder.java:116) at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.connect(Selector.java:203) at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:764) at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.access$600(NetworkClient.java:60) at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:908) at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:819) at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:431) at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:224) at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:162) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to create SaslClient with mechanism GSSAPI at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.createSaslClient(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:140) at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.configure(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:123) ... 10 common frames omittedCaused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Failure to initialize security context at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.<init>(GssKrb5Client.java:149) at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.FactoryImpl.createSaslClient(FactoryImpl.java:63) at javax.security.sasl.Sasl.createSaslClient(Sasl.java:384) at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator$1.run(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:136) at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator$1.run(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:131) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.createSaslClient(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:131) ... 11 common frames omittedCaused by: org.ietf.jgss.GSSException: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm) at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5NameElement.getInstance(Krb5NameElement.java:129) at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getNameElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:95) at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getNameElement(GSSManagerImpl.java:203) at sun.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.getElement(GSSNameImpl.java:477) at sun.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.init(GSSNameImpl.java:201) at sun.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.<init>(GSSNameImpl.java:170) at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.createName(GSSManagerImpl.java:138) at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.<init>(GssKrb5Client.java:107) ... 18 common frames omitted
2019-08-14T09:49:51.949-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] DEBUG [d3-5b28248c661c] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient o.a.k.c.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:773) - ||||||||||||||Error connecting to node abcNode:9094 (id: -1 rack: null): java.io.IOException: Channel could not be created for socket java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[closed] at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.connect(Selector.java:210) at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:764) at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.access$600(NetworkClient.java:60) at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:908) at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:819) at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:431) at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:224) at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:162) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to configure SaslClientAuthenticator at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.buildChannel(SaslChannelBuilder.java:120) at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.connect(Selector.java:203) ... 8 common frames omittedCaused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to configure SaslClientAuthenticator at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.configure(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:125) at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.buildChannel(SaslChannelBuilder.java:116) ... 9 common frames omittedCaused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to create SaslClient with mechanism GSSAPI at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.createSaslClient(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:140) at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.configure(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:123) ... 10 common frames omittedCaused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Failure to initialize security context at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.<init>(GssKrb5Client.java:149) at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.FactoryImpl.createSaslClient(FactoryImpl.java:63) at javax.security.sasl.Sasl.createSaslClient(Sasl.java:384) at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator$1.run(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:136) at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator$1.run(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:131) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.createSaslClient(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:131) ... 11 common frames omittedCaused by: org.ietf.jgss.GSSException: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm) at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5NameElement.getInstance(Krb5NameElement.java:129) at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getNameElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:95) at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getNameElement(GSSManagerImpl.java:203) at sun.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.getElement(GSSNameImpl.java:477) at sun.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.init(GSSNameImpl.java:201) at sun.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.<init>(GSSNameImpl.java:170) at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.createName(GSSManagerImpl.java:138) at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.<init>(GssKrb5Client.java:107) ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Comment: _"This may indicate that authentication failed due to invalid credentials"_ -- Did you ensure the credentials are correct?

Comment: Yes.. as i said, it's working perfectly on local system. same code same configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. I go the solution for this .. might be helpful for others who are stuck around this issue.

First i set the krb5.conf file in Producer Config properties. This file hold the Details of the host, realm and other details required to discover the services using kerberos

```
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf",  <path to conf file>);
```

And instead of setting jaas config directly in properties, i have created jaas conf file and set that in system properties -

Before Code was like this -

```
props.put("sasl.jaas.config", jaasConfig);
```

After changes -

```
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", jaasFile.getPath());
```

Sample Jaas Config File `jaas_client.conf` structure -

```
KafkaClient {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useKeyTab=true
storeKey=true
keyTab="#keytab-name#" 
principal="#principal#";
};
```

*P.S. in `jaas_client.conf` file, i am rewriting the file after updating `#keytab-name#` to actual path of keytab file and `#principal#` values with actual value, before setting to `SystemProperties`*

One can set the debug mode to see the JaaS Authentication and Ticketing logs when debug is enabled using following property -

```
System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", ""+<true/false>);
```